# What is the hooks concept in codeigniter frame work

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have small query that I have refereed books and official website but even though I have doubt .

What is the hooks concept in codeigniter and merits and demerits of hooks ?

could you please tell me.

Comment: This is good, not so much outdated article about this hooks in CI I read few weeks ago http://qasimbadami.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/codeigniter-hooks-tutorial/

Comment: I used hook for stats collection and some other task by following this article.This can help you:http://7degrees.co.uk/blog/simple-stats-collection-with-codeigniter-hooks/

Answer (score 1):

When codeigniter framework runs it performs the operation in some manner as you can see in its flow diagram. Now what will you do if you want to perform some logic in between the system load? For that you can use hooks logic of codeigniter, where you dont need to go inside the core. you just need to implement one of the seven hooks.

For example you want to put your logic just before calling controller. You will use pre_controller hooks for it. For more details you can go through the documentation.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html

Answer (score 0):

With the hook feature you can modify or add a snippet of code without changing the core file. Please look the link below.

```
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html
```

you can call a pre-defined function or class depending on your need with the hook feature.